# UIWebView paragraph selection style

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, textselection

[image: pic1]

as you can see in the first picture ,i'm using the UIWebview in my app.
But when i drag the second handle to the next paragraph , the selection become a rectangle box , i can only select the whole paragraph , how can i keep it just like the first picture?

[image: pic2]

Comment: maybe you can try remembering the initial positions somehow and force-replace auto-bound-to-paragraph secondary changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from reading [Using Copy, Cut and Paste Operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html), you can see that iOS has implemented the UI selection for `UIWebView`, `UITextView` and `UITextField` for you, and thus what you are seeing is simply how selection works in these UI objects.

(and it is thus:  so long as the user is within the bounds of a paragraph, then the user will be able to select a portion of the text in the paragraph as you have demonstrated in your first view; and if the user's fingers run beyond the edges of the paragraph, the underlying UI code showing the selected area will attempt to select the smallest subset of items it can select, with entire paragraphs being considered an atomic unit at this level.)

given that the documentation referenced above describes only how to invoke the various **cut/copy/paste/select** actions when invoked from a menu (with some control over what appears in the `UIMenuController`'s menu, and some control over what you can do with the cut/copied selection in a `UIPasteboard`), there doesn't seem to be a handy way to direct how the UI responds to the user controlling the edge of the selection.  even going so far as extending `UIWebView` might give you the ability to capture the touch events necessary, but you wouldn't be able to direct the resulting drawing of the selection through documented API of `UIWebView`.

and so, without mucking with non-public API, it's a little hard to imagine how you could have a more precise fine-grain control over selecting text spanning paragraphs unless you go to the length of implementing your own class to capture the touch-events necessary to control he selection and then process the events to draw the selection around the edges that you prefer.  in other words, you'd sort of have to re-invent `UIWebView` and all that it does, with the exception of your special code for selections spanning textual paragraphs.

sorry.

Comment: I know about [UITextView setContentToHTMLString:] and with this method  text selection work as I need but unfortunately this is private API. Another trick is to add contentEditable="true" for body node, but it present keyboard and for I don know how to avoid this

Comment: @anton_byrna, you had also mentioned UIWebView, and that would seem to be an additional hindrance to using the private API and contentEditable value to get done what you desire.

Comment: In my project I load my own html so I can add contentEditable attribute without any problem

Comment: @anton_byrna, i guess i'm not certain of the point of your comment. are you saying that you plan on implementing your own extensions, and that since you are loading your own html, using the contentEditable attribute will help you do so? with this much, i would agree. if you are saying that playing with the contentEditable attribute is going to change the bounds of that blue area in the way you want without writing your own extensions, then i'm at a loss as to where you are going with that.